# 行列指数関数の極限をとりたい

Tags: python, python3, sympy

このコードによって表示される行列指数関数を、tを無限に飛ばしたときにどんな行列になるのかを表示させたいです。`sym.limit()` は試しましたが、要素を飛ばすことはできないようです。

```
import sympy as sym

A = sym.Matrix([
    [1, 0],
    [0,1]])

t=sym.symbols("t")
At=A*t
At.exp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こういうことでしょうか？

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np

A = sym.Matrix([
    [1, 0],
    [0,1]])

t=sym.symbols("t")
At=A*t
At.exp().subs(t, sym.oo)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

要素ごとに極限を取ってはどうでしょう？

```py
At.exp().applyfunc(lambda x: sym.limit(x, t, sym.oo))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。それもありですね。とても参考になりました